# ASP.Net MVC - Use WebResponse as a JavaScript Variable on Page Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

As soon as my page loads I would like to make a web request so that its response can be accessed via JavaScript. I have written a c# class that makes the requests to the server. This class is invoked by a controller in my MVC application. I can confirm that the client class is functioning properly & returns a string representation of the JSON.

My question is this. How should I call the controller so that I can use the response in my javascript? The @http.Action simply returns a txt file containing the html of the whole page with the response in the place that i make the call. I would like to instead store this as a variable and maintaining the initial Index view..

Code Bellow has been modified to only include essentials.

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult getMeterConfig () {
        string scheme = "http";
        string host = "*****";
        int port = ****;
        string dataset = "*****";
        string db = "****";
        string method = "GET";

        var request = new client();
        request.setProps(scheme, host, port, dataset, db, method);
        request.makeRequest();
        var response = request.getResponse();

        return Json (response,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

Then to call the controller on page load:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var json = @Html.Action("actionName","contollerName";
});
```

**EDIT For Clarification**

Ive changed the javascript to be :

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        $.get('@Html.Action("getMeterConfig", "GetMeterConfig")', function (response) {
            var meters = response;
        });
    });
```

This returns a download entitled Index.json rather than store the response in the variable meters.

[image]

To make this even more peculiar the .json document reads as follows... It includes my index view HTML and substitutes the  @Html.Action("getMeterConfig", "GetMeterConfig") with the actual response.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would make an AJAX request to that controller action.  Assuming jQuery, since ASP.NET MVC comes with it:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.get('@Url.Action("getMeterConfig", "contollerName")', function (response) {
        var json = response;
    });
});
```

So when your client-side page loads, that client-side code would make a separate request to this `getMeterConfig` action.  The JSON returned by that request would be available in the callback function.  (I named the variable `response` but you can call it whatever you like.)

Comment: This makes so much sense! I applied these suggestions yet still get a download that is entitled index.json  and contains the markup for the whole page. Example: it contains the html, head, script tags, body etc.. then it appends the response inside of the script where we declared var json = response. Any thoughts? Is it because the controller is returning json?

Comment: @LCaraway: Well, what is the response that `getMeterConfig` is returning?  If the 3rd party page is returning HTML and you're returning whatever they return, then you're also returning HTML.

Comment: The service the calls are hitting is an API managed by us. The HTML it is also including is the very html of my index view on the home controller. Using fiddler i can confirm that only the Array of JSON is being returned.. Example [{object 1},{object 2}] which is what is expected.

Comment: Yet my application upon completion of the call returns a download of the html of the index with the response appended in place of the @html.Acrion(...)

Comment: @LCaraway: It's really not clear what you're describing.  Can you provide more complete information in the question?  Perhaps a more complete working demonstration of the problem?

Comment: I've made an edit to include more detail with what i am seeing.

Comment: @LCaraway: Hmm... There may be a typo in both the question and the answer.  I think it should be `@Url.Action` instead of `@Html.Action`.  Basically, it just needs to be the URL for invoking the AJAX request.  To debug, you should also examine the source of the page to make sure the JavaScript code is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Aha! this was it. URL.Action was the solution.